# Change owning user and group on file creation

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, php, scp, file-copy

I have an issue where I want to connect a very old system (UNIX) to a new machine. This old machine logs in by `scp` using a hardcoded `oldsystemaccess` user and copies a file into a subdirectory of the new servers webroot `/var/www/newserver/test/import`. The new machine is running an Ubuntu 18 LAMP stack with no advanced configuration done to the apache, running as `www-data` in that same group.

On the new server, I added this user `oldsystemaccess` to the `www-data` group using `sudo usermod -aG www-data oldsystemaccess` and I changed the permissions on the directory to `rwxrwxr-x` with `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/newserver/test/import`. After this change, the file was successfully copied over to the new system.

Now the actual issue I am trying to fix: when the files are owned by `oldsystemaccess` my PHP scripts cannot read or handle the files properly and since I am unable to change the way the files are copied from the old server or run additional commands when they are I am looking for a way to change the files created in the directory `import` to be owned by `www-data` user and group on creation.

For now I added a `crontab` entry running `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/newserver/test/import` every minute but I feel like it is a really bad solution. I am looking for something like `umask` but for the file ownership.

Comment: Actually, I think the solution to the problem I am having is to make the files inside the directory accessible to the group by default. Something like https://superuser.com/questions/612771/how-to-set-umask-for-a-folder-and-its-subfolder/1648073#1648073

Comment: It may be even simpler than that. Read the man page for `chmod` and search for `setuid`.

Comment: Yes, in theory that is exactly what I am looking for. After further reading I found out that the behaviour I desire is not commonly implemented on Linux for the ``setuid`` bit. But for ``setgid``, it works; so maybe I can make something work with that. I will try to use an ACL when I'm back at my desk tomorrow.

Comment: @JimL. `setuid` only works on binary executables. It’s not going to have any effect on php scripts, data files, or directories.

Comment: @doneal24 One applies the `setuid` bit to the **directory**.  Per the man page: `Directories with this bit set will force all files and sub-directories created in them to be owned by the directory owner and not by the uid of the creating process, if the underlying file system supports this feature: see chmod(2)`

Comment: @JimL. On a few systems  `setuid` on directories works but not by default on any Linux system. This is from the Gnu [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html). Are you possibly looking at a bsd man page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some systems (like FreeBSD if you believe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#When_set_on_a_directory)), the `setuid` bit on a directory would have my desired behaviour ([Link](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html#Directories-and-the-Set_002dUser_002dID-and-Set_002dGroup_002dID-Bits)). But since it is not default behaviour on the Ubuntu I am running I found the solution for the problem I am having was the following:

Set the `setgid` bit using `chmod` so new files are owned by the `www-data` group.

`sudo chmod 2775 /var/www/newserver/test/import`

Apparently the script copying the files has an `umask` of `007` set, which caused files to be created with `rwxrwx---` permissions, but I overlooked this when asking the question.

If you need the write-permission bit set on files inside the directory you can then set up an ACL to automatically make files writeable by the group that owns them:

`sudo setfacl -d -m group:www-data:rwx /var/www/newserver/import`

Comment: That looks like it should work.  Note that with chmod 4775 you are actually setting the `setuid` bit, not the `setgid` bit.  Since your `oldsystemaccess` user is in the `www-data` group and the directory `/var/www/newserver/test/import` is group-writeable, I don't think anything else is necessary.  Try removing that ACL and using just the `chmod 4775 ...` and it may still work.  If the files created aren't group-readable, then your ACL might be needed, or an adjustment of the `oldsystemaccess` user's `umask` value would fix that, also.  `umask 22`, for instance, rather than say, `umask 77`

Comment: Come to think of it, if the `oldsystemaccess` user's primary group is `www-data`, and if the `/var/www/newserver/import` directory is group-writeable, `chmod 775`, and if `oldsystemaccess` has an effective `umask 22`, then neither the ACL nor the `setuid` will be necessary.  At that point, the user will have write permission to the directory, files created will be owned `oldsystemaccess:www-data` and file perms will be `644`.

Comment: Even without the primary group changed it now apparently works.. file ownership is ``oldsystemaccess:oldsystemaccess`` and yet PHP is now able to edit, move and delete the files. I'm confused.